# Change background of each last cell in a row - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table. I want to change the background of each last cell in a row.  Currently is is working for the last row > last cell only.

HTML:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>1 col</td>
        <td>2 col</td>
        <td>3 col</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1 col</td>
        <td>2 col</td>
        <td>3 col</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1 col</td>
        <td>2 col</td>
        <td>3 col</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery -

```
 $("tr").each(function () {
        $("td:last").addClass("highlight");
    });
```

Fiddle-
http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4TN/1/

I want to perform this with only JQuery (don't want to add class or id's in html).Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `:last-child` selector here, no need to iterate elements.

```
$("tr td:last-child").addClass('highlight');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4TN/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4TN/2/)

```
   $("tr").each(function () {
      $(this).find("td:last").addClass("highlight");
  });
```

Comment: Is is working.. hence upvoted it. But one line code is always good. Check the answer made by Rajaprabhu.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table tr td:last-child").addClass("highlight");
```

and here's an update to jsfiddle of yours:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4TN/3/